# Puppeteer not rendering content on PDF (invisible text)

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, puppeteer

Only sometimes, I get a PDF rendered from Puppeter without any content:

[image]

On the picture above, we are missing all the content inside the `table` element, as well as the content beside **NIF** and **Número D-U-N-S**.

It is an inconsistent error, because most of the times it works properly, but sometimes not.

Here you can see the way we launch Puppeteer:

```
const launchParams = {
  args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', 'displayHeaderFooter', 'preferCSSPageSize', 'printBackground']
};
// Launch the browser and create a page
browser = await puppeteer.launch(launchParams);
const page = await browser.newPage();

requestOptions.timeout = 0;
requestOptions.waitUntil = 'networkidle2';

await page.goto(urlOrHtml, requestOptions);
await page.emulateMedia('print');
```

The font color is black (as I said, most of the times it works well and you can see the text).

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same issue. I am not sure (came here for an answer), but I have an hypothesis.

In my case, I am using web fonts, and I explicitly chose `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,400&display=block`, meaning I get font faces like

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: block;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1Mu51xEIzIXKMnyrYk.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
```

Using `font-display: block`. See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display).

Also, there is no fall-back font:

```
body {
  …
  font-family: Roboto;
  …
}
```

I really want that font, consistently, and not some fall-back.

`font-display: block` ["Gives the font face a short block period and an infinite swap period."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display).

> Font block period
>
> If the font face is not loaded, any element attempting to use it must
> render an ***invisible fallback font face***. If the font face
> successfully loads during this period, it is used normally.

So, the hypothesis is that, sometimes the web font loads in time, and sometimes it does not. When it does not, the invisible font is used.

I added ttf fonts to my lambda, in the hope this would force their use, as they are always available, avoiding this timing issue. But, that doesn't work.

Next, I'll try to remove the web fonts from the CSS. Will that force using the TTF fonts?

Comment: For anyone coming to this issue now, make sure you have `block` at the end of your Google Fonts call or have `font-display: block` on your font-face declaration. If using Puppeteer, use https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.waitfornetworkidle to make sure that all pending network requests have ended before generating the PDF.